# ClassNotFoundException and ClassCastException with lein-droid

Tags: clojure, classnotfoundexception, classcastexception

When building a lein-droid project with `[clj-http "0.7.7"]` as  a dependency in project.clj, it fails with the following error [0]:

```
Compiling cheshire.jsonp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.Json, compiling:(jsonp.clj:1:1)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.json.Json
[...]
```

Replacing the dependency with `[cheshire "5.2.0"]` (current version) produces the same error. Lowering the version to "5.1.1" removes this error.

Adding `[clj-http "0.7.7"]` as a dependency to the project introduces a new error [1]:

```
Compiling clj-http.conn-mgr
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException clj_http.conn_mgr$fn$reify__20 cannot be cast to java.security.KeyStore, compiling:(conn_mgr.clj:13:3)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: clj_http.conn_mgr$fn$reify__20 cannot be cast to java.security.KeyStore
[...]
```

Relevant settings from project.clj (set from the lein-droid tutorial):

```
:javac-options ["-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "-Xlint:-options"]
:android { ...
    :target-version "16"
...}
```

Changing these settings to the current version numbers doesn't change the error.

**With cheshire 5.2.0**

```
» lein deps :tree          
WARNING!!! possible confusing dependencies found:
[clojure-complete "0.2.3"]
 overrides
[clojure-complete "0.2.3"]

[cheshire "5.1.1"]
 overrides
[clj-http "0.7.7"] -> [cheshire "5.2.0"]
```

**Without cheshire in dependencies**

```
» lein deps :tree     
WARNING!!! possible confusing dependencies found:
[org.clojure/data.json "0.2.3"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
 overrides
[clj-http "0.7.7"] -> [cheshire "5.2.0"] -> [tigris "0.1.1"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]

[clojure-complete "0.2.3"]
 overrides
[clojure-complete "0.2.3"]
```

Comment: you're having a dependency mismatch because some dependency is bringing in an old version of a library, what's the output of `lein deps :tree` and the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I added the output of `lein deps :tree` to the question, it seems highly relevant. I'll post the stack traces later if needed, as they clutter the post too much.